# GTK in C - How to control colum width in treeview?

Tags: c, gtk

I am using gtk treeview to make a simple table in c.

I am doing so with the following:

```
tree_view = gtk_tree_view_new();    
store = gtk_list_store_new(4, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);      
gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view), GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));   

renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view), -1, "Register", renderer, "text", 0, NULL);
gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view), -1, "Value", renderer, "text", 1, NULL);
gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view), -1, "Type", renderer, "text", 2, NULL);    
gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(tree_view), -1, "Description", renderer, "text", 3, NULL);  

GtkTreeIter iter;
gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
gtk_list_store_set 

etc.
```

How am I able to control the width of each individual column?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not all of them may be required).

```
gtk_tree_view_column_set_fixed_width (col, w); // just a hint
gtk_tree_view_column_set_min_width (col, w);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_max_width (col, w)
gtk_tree_view_column_set_sizing (col, GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED)
```

RTM for specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `gtk_tree_view_column_set_resizable()`